# Does Win32_PnPEntity stores device history? In other words, it always returns ONLY connected pnp entities?

Tags: winapi, wmi

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-pnpentity) on `Win32_PnPEntity.Present`

> **Present**
>
> **Data type**: boolean
>
> **Access type**: Read-only
>
> **Qualifiers**: MappingStrings ("WMI")
>
> Whether this Plug and Play device is currently in the system.
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 ?> R2, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista: This property is not supported.

I would assume that if the API provides a `Present` property, I can expect to find devices where `Present` is false.
However, I am unable to find such (using queries such as `Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity where Present = False"`). I have usb devices connected right now (and if I replace "False" with "True", they show up in the results).

I mean, I had in mind that querying `Win32_PnPEntity` will always return **ONLY** connected/present pnp entities.
**Will this not always hold true** ?

If this always holds true, then what's the point in the API providing a "Present" field if its value is a constant ?
If this is not always true, could you please provide an example of a query that returns results for `Present = False` ?